# Behaviour of Gradle/Maven for circular dependencies

Tags: maven, gradle, circular-dependency

I am currently filling a Maven repository with our "non-Maven" jars, so that future projects in Maven/Gradle can use them. Unfortunately, we have some circular dependencies in the "non-Maven" projects. My question is now, what happens in Maven or Gradle, if they encounter

- A true circular dependency, like foo-1.0.0.jar -> bar-1.0.0-jar -> foo-1.0.0.jar
- An "old version circle" as foo-3.0.0.jar uses bar-2.0.0.jar and bar-2.0.0.jar uses foo-1.0.0.jar.

This is not about building foo.jar or bar.jar, but about building projects which depend on either foo.jar or bar.jar.

Comment: For checking in Maven you can use http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banCircularDependencies.html

Comment: Does anyone know whether Gradle behaves identical to Maven as described in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A true circular dependency will result in an error: Maven will fail the build directly. A circular dependency happens when you transivitely depend on an artifact that has the same [Maven coordinates](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates) as the current project: `groupId`, `artifactId`, `version`, `packaging` and `classifier`. Generally, we're dealing with `jar` with no classifier so having the same `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version` is what generally defines a circular dependency.

An old version circle is not a circle *per se*, because the Maven coordinates are not the same. In that case, Maven will just keep the newer version by applying [dependency mediation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies):

> which means that it will use the version of the closest dependency to your project in the tree of dependencies

---

As [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) points out, if you're looking to fail the build even in the case of an old version circle, you can configure the `maven-enforcer-plugin` to ban it with the [`banCircularDependencies`](http://www.mojohaus.org/extra-enforcer-rules/banCircularDependencies.html) extra rule.

Comment: So is it only a circle if it comes back to the current project? What about circles in dependencies? my-project depends on foo.jar which depends on bar.jar which depends on foo.jar.

Comment: @JFMeier There can't be a circle in a dependency: it wouldn't have been able to be built in the first place :)

Comment: This is not true if it wasn't built with Maven/Gradle in the first place. I am transfering old jars to the repository and generate POMs for them.

Comment: @JFMeier Well if you're writing the POM by hand and introducing explicitly a circular dependency, I _think_ Maven will also fail but I admit I've never done this before. It would be quite surprising if it didn't though.